# @Jupyterlab/git - Can not clone repositories

Tags: git, github, jupyter, github-api, jupyter-lab

I currently installed the following plugin for Jupyter lab:

https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-git

It was successfully installed. But every time I try to clone a repository, or push an existing local rep, I get the following error:

Error: Unhandled error.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

EDIT!!

Here is my git --version:

1. git version 2.31.1.windows.1

My installed extensions:

1. @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v3.0.0
2. @jupyterlab/git v0.30.1
3. nbdime-jupyterlab v2.1.0
4. jupyterlab-horizon-theme v3.0.1

---

Results of jupyter serverextension list and jupyter server extension list:

[image: Command Prompt Print]

Comment: Hi Lucas, I think that more details will be needed to be able to help you. Please provide the full traceback of the error if available, the version of your JupyterLab, the output of `jupyter labextension list` and `git --version`. Also, have you tried searching [the list of issue](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-git/issues?q=is%3Aissue+Unhandled+error+) for anything similar? There seems to be 12 hits for this error message.

Comment: Hello Krassowski! I'm going to take a depper look at the list of issues and edit my question to provide those infos.

Comment: Please remember to provide the versions of installed extensions/JupyterLab - these are crucial.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, there you go!

Comment: Do you have the server extension installed as well? What is the exact output of `jupyter serverextension list` and `jupyter server extension list` (notice an extra space)? How did you install jutyterlab-git?

Comment: Hello Krassowski! I added an screenshot of those output.